# What would the equivalent query be in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am starting to use PL/SQL and to know how to use DATEDIFF, DATEADD

`select DATEADD(HH, 1, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd,0, GETDATE()),0))`

What would the equivalent query be in oracle

Comment: This is not PL/SQL, just plain oracle SQL you need to convert to.  Please show some attempt.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that there *are* worse things in this world than Oracle's date/time support.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the goal is to return a date where the day is today and the time is 1am

```
trunc(sysdate) + interval '1' hour
```

or

```
trunc(sysdate) + 1/24
```

would both work.  I prefer the interval syntax since it's a bit more intuitive but you'll encounter the latter syntax pretty frequently.